# execv call in C

Tags: c++, c, linux, signals

There is a simple program below that takes a  HUP and continues with execv. The problem is when the execv call is executed, after that the code continues from the places where the HUP comes.I want, after execv the code must exit from main and than start again from the beginning of main.

```
char* a;
char** args;

void hup_func(){
    printf("aaaa\n");
    if(execv(a,args))
        printf("bbb\n");
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    signal(SIGHUP,hup_func);
    args=argv;
    a=args[0];
    printf("%s\n",a);
    while(1){
        printf("test\n");
        sleep(10);
     }

   return 0;
}
```

The name of the program is deneme1. The output of the code is when I sent HUP;

```
./deneme1
test
test
aaa 
bbbb
test.
```

But I want it, when I sent HUP, it must start with the start of the main. like that

```
./deneme1
test
test
aaa
bbb
./deneme1
test
...
```

I want it to return at the beginning of the main after HUP, not the place where it was before

Comment: Umm, so write code to make it do what you want. One way is [longjmp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h#Exception_handling).

Comment: As you can see, execv() fails. This is asserted by **bbbb** printed to stdout. And your code & output doesn't match.

Comment: @barp: There is another problem I've outlined in my answer with blocked signals after the call to `execv` does complete successfully.  See my updated answer for the solution to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not sending the correct arguments to `execv`, and therefore the function is exiting with an error. So you're simply exiting the signal handler rather than overlaying the process with a new copy of the process.

The argument signature for `execv` is:

```
int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
```

The second argument should be an array of `const` pointers to `char`, with the last element being a `NULL` pointer. The `char* a` that you're passing for the second argument is not the correct type.

Finally, `execv` is not considered an [asynchronous signal-safe function](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers), where-as it's sister-function, `execve` is.  You should use the latter.  The same is also true for any of the `printf` family of functions ... if you need to write to the terminal, use `write` instead.

**Update**: I re-ran your updated code.  The program is restarting properly, but the problem is that the signal mask is being inherited from the original process that was overlaid by the call to `execv`.  Since you are running `execv` from inside a signal-handler, the `SIGHUP` will be blocked in the overlaid process, and you won't be able to send any other `SIGHUP` signals to the process.  To undo this, you need to unblock the `SIGHUP` signal using `sigprocmask()` right after you assign your signal-handler using `signal()`.

For instance, change your `main` to:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    sigset_t signal_mask;

    signal(SIGHUP,hup_func);

    //unblock the SIGHUP signal if it's blocked
    sigaddset(&signal_mask, SIGHUP);
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &signal_mask, NULL);

    args=argv;
    a=args[0];
    printf("%s\n",a);
    while(1){
        printf("test\n");
        sleep(10);
     }

   return 0;
}
```

I've compiled and run this on Ubuntu 12.04, and it now runs perfectly.

Comment: I'm looking at the signature [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) ... you're not passing the correct arguments, and if you checked for an error return from `execv`, you'd see that it's bailing on you.

Comment: I added the condition control and edited the code. the output seems true.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is when the execv call is executed, after that the code continues from the places where the HUP comes

There is no error checking in your code, most likely `execv()` call fails.

Try amending it like:

```
char** gargv;

void hup_func() {
    execvp(*gargv, gargv);
    abort(); // must never get here
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    // ...
    gargv = argv;
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Jason pointed, **execv** is failing. Test yourself with this code.

```
#include<signal.h>
char* a;
char **args;

void hup_func(){
    printf("receivied SIGHUP\n");
    execv(a,a);
    printf("execv failed\n");
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    int b =0;
    printf("setting signal handler for SIGHUP\n");
    signal(SIGHUP,hup_func);
    args=argv;
    a=argv[0];
    printf("Before entering while %s\n",a);
    while(1){
        printf("In while %d\n",++b);
        sleep(1);
     }

   return 0;
}
```

Then replace

```
   execv(a,a);
```

with

```
   execv(a,args);
```

Comment: it does not matter. you can say the signature is like that. but a null char** can bu equal char*. if you try your code and my code you will see no difference

Comment: Please read my response fully. The code as i given will print **execv failed** as you are passing wrong argument types. Then replace  **execv(a,a);** with **execv(a,args);**

Comment: Yes I replaced it. and the result is same.I will edit my question what I do.